# nodejs express mysql query with 'SET @'XXX''

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, parameters, routes

I am working on nodejs/express app. In my routes i need to query data from MySQL database. It's working fine with exceptions for the queries that have parameters in them.
Any query without parameters work as expected:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE col = 'b'
```

But the one below returns `undefined`

```
 SET @a = 'b'
 SELECT * FROM table where col = @a
```

I generate string for queries in separate function (not sure if that makes any difference).
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It would help if you posted the code you use to talk to the db, not just the sql statement

Comment: @twoleggedhorse. I am using standard const db = require('../server'); db.query(query, result). That's working fine. My issue is with query with parameters only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may be looking for the `?` placeholder method, described at

https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_mysql_where.asp

```
var adr = 'Mountain 21';
var sql = 'SELECT * FROM customers WHERE address = ?';
con.query(sql, [adr], function (err, result) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(result);
});
```

There's also multiple placeholders too, passed in as an array:

```
var name = 'Amy';
var adr = 'Mountain 21';
var sql = 'SELECT * FROM customers WHERE name = ? OR address = ?';
con.query(sql, [name, adr], function (err, result) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for that. It will work for the some of my queries with slight modifications, which is great. However some of them have dynamic statements i.e. "PREPARE dynamic_statement FROM @query; EXECUTE dynamic_statement any ideas how to handle those.

Comment: Must it be completely dynamic? That is usually described as a code "smell", could you give an example?

Comment: The following is an example of building a statement dynamically that may fit your needs https://blog.stvmlbrn.com/2018/07/27/dynamic-where-clauses-with-parameterized-queries-in-node-mysql.html

Comment: Not sure what "code smell" but it doesn't sound too encouraging. Under current table structures it has to be dynamic. Below is some code (I replaced @ with #):
let strMjrRank ='SET #userid = '" + userid + "';
SET #cip1 := (SELECT ….  FROM xxx WHERE xxx.ut_userid = #userid);
SET #cip1m := (LEFT(#cip1,6));
SET #w1 := CAST(RIGHT(#cip1,LENGTH(#cip1)-INSTR(#cip1,'_')) AS SIGNED);
SET #query := CONCAT('SELECT ……  ((', #cip1m, ' * ', #w1, ') + …..)
PREPARE dynamic_statement FROM #query;
EXECUTE dynamic_statement;

cip1m is a column name from a table.

Comment: Perhaps a sql function would be better? Just pass in the user id and away you go, everything is then in sql and you can do the more complex stuff there. Alternatively, do multiple database calls; one to get cip1, do your string manipulation in code to get your other values. Now you have all you need for your final db call..

Comment: Which one is the best practice way? Sql function or multiple calls? My query is quite involved.

Comment: That entirely depends on what you're doing, if you have set coding standards, what source control you're using, if you are writing with a code or database first methodology. I would personally prefer to use a function over inline sql.

Comment: No standards. Just trying to learn new things. I have databases first. I will give a try to sql function. Thanks for all your help.